# Spring Boot 3 forward problem: GET to POST

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

I have a `Job`s listing where I have a link to enable editing:

```
<a href="/editprep?id=81" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
```

The idea is to 'prepare' the editing and then forward to the form that will allow editing, followed by saving. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Aug 14 13:41:33 BST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
```

and in the console I see:

```
2023-08-14T13:41:33.877+01:00  WARN 7881 --- [qtp603184112-33] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]
```

The controller method for this is:

```
    //@ModelAttribute
    @RequestMapping(value="/editprep", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editPrep(@RequestParam String id, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.printf("Would edit job with ID %s%n", id);
        Job editingJob = repository.findById(Long.valueOf(id)).orElseThrow();
        model.addAttribute("editingJob", editingJob);
        /*
        System.out.println(model);
        System.out.println("Found job " + editingJob);
        */
        //return "redirect:/editjob";
        return new ModelAndView("forward:/editjob", model);
        //return "controlpanel";
    }
```

(messy as as lot of fruitless trial and error has gone on here)
The idea is to forward to the form for editing, to be saved in the following:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/editjob", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editJob(@RequestParam String date, @RequestParam String place, @RequestParam String amount, @RequestParam boolean billed, @RequestParam boolean paid, @RequestParam String notes) {
        return "/";
    }
```

This is essentially the same as create/save, so I should do some code reuse here.
How do I solve this coding error? Do I have a logical/flow error too?

Comment: Status codes 301-307 [do not allow method changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#permanent_redirections). Status code 308 might, depending on if your client supports it.

Comment: It's probably easier to handle this not using a redirect, but simply by calling the code internally.

Comment: tbh I *did* think of doing it internally but then I didn't want to 'duck out' of learning the technology and also not sure of exactly how to do it. There are quite a lot of closely related model classes and then you've got the varying tech between different Spring versions, etc. I might settle at least on a Spring 3 way of doing it internallly